# How to see this inequality?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have an $(n\times n)$-matrix $A(t)$ and an $n$-vector $b(t)$ that depend continously on $t$. Let $u\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ some function.

In a proof, I found the following inequality:
$$
2\lVert A(t)\rVert u + 2\lVert b(t)\rVert\sqrt{u}\leq(2\lVert A(t)\rVert+\lVert b(t)\rVert +1)u.
$$

I do not see how to get this inequality.

My first idea only was that $2\lVert b(t)\rVert\sqrt{u}\leq \lVert b(t)\rVert^2+u$, and so I got
$$
2\lVert A(t)\rVert u + 2\lVert b(t)\rVert\sqrt{u}\leq (2\lVert A(t)\rVert+1)u+\lVert b(t)\rVert^2.
$$

Comment: Do you know anything else about $u$ ? Is it a function of $t$ ?

Comment: It is a function of $t$.